# Connection to Hbase using python is failing

Tags: python, hadoop, hbase, happybase

I am trying to connect to Hbase using python 
sample code used

```
import happybase
connection = happybase.Connection(myhost,port, autoconnect=True)

# before first use:
connection.open()
print(connection.tables())
```

which is giving error as follows

> > > print(connection.tables())
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/happybase/connection.py", line 242, in tables
> > >           names = self.client.getTableNames()
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thriftpy/thrift.py", line 198, in _req
> > >           return self._recv(_api)
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thriftpy/thrift.py", line 210, in _recv
> > >           fname, mtype, rseqid = self._iprot.read_message_begin()
> > >         File "thriftpy/protocol/cybin/cybin.pyx", line 439, in cybin.TCyBinaryProtocol.read_message_begin (thriftpy/protocol/cybin/cybin.c:6470)
> > >       cybin.ProtocolError: No protocol version header

OS : Ubuntu 16.04
I am using python 2.7 
Hbase Version  1.1
Help me to understand the issue.Is there any better way to connect to Hbase other than happybase

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for asking the question, I did fall into the same issue, where there is no answer on the internet. Not sure are we the only one hitting to this or not.

But here is how I figured out to fix the issue, from the error its clear that its something to do with thrift, so check the following

`/usr/hdp/current/hbase-master/bin/hbase-daemon.sh start thrift`

if thrift is not running! you may need to start thrift

`/usr/hdp/current/hbase-master/bin/hbase-daemon.sh start thrift -p 9090 --infoport 9091`

then try your code.

```py
import happybase

c = happybase.Connection('127.0.0.1',9090, autoconnect=False)
c.open()
print(c.tables())
```

Auto Connection to hbase

```py
import happybase

c = happybase.Connection('127.0.0.1',9090)
print(c.tables())
```

As an alternative you an use *starbase* but its no longer active i belive for this you need to start rest API.
 `/usr/hdp/current/hbase-master/bin/hbase-daemon.sh start rest -p 8000 --inforport 8001` 
Try the happybase and let us know if you are hitting to same issue.

BTW my testing was done on HDP2.5

Further reference:
https://github.com/wbolster/happybase/issues/161

***which i dont recommend unless you know what you are doing***

remove the following property: from hbase-site.xml [/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml]

```html
<property>
  <name>hbase.regionserver.thrift.http</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.thrift.support.proxyuser</name>
  <value>true/value>
</property>
```

Hope this helps,
Amod

Answer (score 0):

Either you do `autoconnect = True` or you start it explicitly using `connection.open()`. You don't have to do both together.

Answer (score 0):

`happybase.Connection(myhost, port, autoconnect=True)`

here port is the thrift server port, by default, the value is 9090.
If you are using docker, you should export the port 9090 from host to your docker container.

exec into your container, and start the thrift server:

```
/opt/hbase-1.2.5/hbase thrift2 start

2024-02-02 09:11:25,080 INFO  [main] http.HttpServer: Jetty bound to port 9095
2024-02-02 09:11:25,080 INFO  [main] mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2024-02-02 09:11:26,630 INFO  [main] mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9095
2024-02-02 09:11:26,644 INFO  [main] thrift2.ThriftServer: starting HBase ThreadPool Thrift server on 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9090
```